# clearing buffer when using GL_OVR_Multiview

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

with multiview extension, single draw call is made for multiple views. but how does it work when i dont have any draw call ? lets say i have 2 views, i setup the FBO and array textures. Now i bind FBO, just call `glClear` and `glClearColor` without any draw call, does it copy clear data to both the layers?

I am having bug with my implementation, if i dont execute any draw call, i see some corruption on first view whereas second view looks fine. if i call drawinstanced, if my object is out of frustum, initially i see corruption but when bring that object into frustum, that corrupted data gets replaced by my object and after that if my object goes out of frustum , i don't see any corruption on my first view. so it seems that something wrong with initial data in texture attachment, but not sure exactly what's going wrong.